# Counting rooftops in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, basemap

In part of a city, I am trying to count rooftops on a basemap/Google satellite in QGIS and create several polygons around x number of rooftops in the area. One similar question like mine was previously asked, but the response was only explained how to do it in Arcmap, not QGIS.

Is there anyway to do it in QGIS?

Comment: See also: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/284522/81764, https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/295643/81764, https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/17558/81764